# AngularJS directive with xeditable: how to pass onbeforesave to directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive, x-editable

I am using xeditable within the directive. This is working fine. However, I am unable to get onbeforesave (and others) to work.  Below is the outline of my angularjs code:

```
app.directive('view', function () {
    return {
        scope: { field: "=", onbeforesave: "&" },
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<a href="#" deditable-text="field" onbeforesave="onbeforesave(field, $data)">{{ field || "empty" }}</a>'
    }
});
```

in index.html:

```
...
<view field="userObj" onbeforesave="fieldChanged()">
...
</view>
```

In my controller.js

```
 ...
 $scope.userObj = "xyz";
 $scope.fieldChanged = function (field, newValue) {
    alert('fieldChanged called');
 }
```

My problem is that $scope.fieldChanged() was never called.  Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Typo? missing function keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing word `Function`

```
$scope.fieldChanged = function (field, newValue) {
alert('fieldChanged called');
```

}